# Clojure as a first programming language?

Tags: clojure, jvm

Thanks for taking the time to read. I’m interested in trying out Clojure for my first programming language--at least, the first programming language in which I intend to commit myself to becoming proficient.

Comment: Why the tag spam? And what is your question now? Yes, get a book.

Comment: Great! You're not really asking a question, so that's why this has been closed. There really is nothing wrong with learning Clojure as your first programming language. To get started, I suggest you setup the [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org) build tool. Also, the book [Clojure Programming](http://www.clojurebook.com/) is the most recent book on the language. For a slightly more advanced book, try [The Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com/). I hope that helps you get your feet wet!

Comment: Many Universities use Scheme as a first programming language and programmers who start this way often go on to lead happy lives ;) So I say go for it, and perhaps you will get more direction from the #clojure channel in irc.freenode.net